# Roll back Gcloud Redis upgrade

Tags: redis, gcloud

I like to upgrade the redis memorystore instance in our gcloud because 5.x (at least in Github) appears to have reached its end of life. It's being use for simple key value pairs, so I don't expect anything unexpected during the upgrade to 6.x. However management is nervous and wants a way to rollback the upgrade if there are issues. Is there a way to do this? The documentation appears to say that rollback is not possible. I plan to do the usual backup and then upgrade. The instance is just the basic.

Comment: posted an answer, is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to Upgrade the redis memorystore instance, follow the best practices mentioned in the Public [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/upgrading-instance-version#best_practices_for_upgrading_an_instances_redis_version) as the following :

> - We recommend [exporting](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/export-data) your instance data before running a    version upgrade operation.
> - Note that upgrading an instance is irreversible. You cannot downgrade    the Redis version of a Memorystore for a Redis instance.
> - For Standard Tier instances, to increase the speed and reliability of    your version upgrade operation, upgrade your instance during
>   periods    of low instance traffic. To learn how to monitor instance
>   traffic,    see [Monitoring Redis instances](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/monitoring-instances).

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/rdb-snapshots) which recommends you to enable RDB Snapshots.

> Memorystore for Redis is primarily used as an in-memory cache. When
> using Memorystore as a cache, your application can either tolerate
> loss of cache data or can very easily repopulate the cache from a
> persistent store.
>
> However, there are some use cases where downtime for a Memorystore
> instance, or a complete loss of instance data, can cause long
> application downtimes. We recommend using the Standard Tier as the
> primary mechanism for high availability. Additionally, enabling RDB
> snapshots on Standard Tier instances provides extra protection from
> failures that can cause cache flushes. The Standard Tier provides a
> highly available instance with multiple replicas, and enables fast
> recovery using automatic failover if the primary fails.
>
> In some scenarios you may also want to ensure data can be recovered
> from snapshot backups in the case of catastrophic failure of Standard
> Tier instances. In these scenarios, automated backups and the ability
> to restore data from RDB snapshots can provide additional protection
> from data loss. With RDB snapshots enabled, if needed, a recovery is
> made from the latest RDB snapshot.

For more information, you can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/version-upgrade-behavior) related to version upgrade behavior.